# HTML Form: Insert id from related table

Tags: insert

I'm relatively new to both php and mysql and here's my first question:

I have 3 tables. One as the "main table" and two as basically lists/categories of which I can choose and relate them to my main table. So:

Table 1

```
id    name    hobby    color
1     Peter   1        2
2     Simon   3        2
3     Lisa    2        3
```

Table 2 would then be hobbies

```
id    name
1     Swimming
2     Football
3     Piano
```

Same with table 3 and colors.

```
id    name
1     red
2     blue
3     green
```

Now, I have managed to "relate" the tables with *phpmyadmin*, but how can I do the following:

I wanna insert data into the first table. But the thing is, I wanna insert a simple number in hobbies or colors. But within the html form, there should be the text related to the is.

So if i choose 'green'(as a string), it should insert 3 into Table 1.

I hope it's clear what i want :D 
Thanks for every help in advance.

Simon

Answer (score 0):

Create your html like this:

```html
<select name="color">
  <option value="1">red</option>
  <option value="2">blue</option>
</select>
```

When an user select "blue" the value of input.color is "2". So an end user selects an string/color and you can insert the int/id